# Having a minor XSLT issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XSL stylesheet working perfectly well in Mozilla Firefox 45 where I made a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//case/events/event/document">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Further down in the stylesheet I call this template with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//case/events/event/document"/>
```

In Firefox it works fine, but in Google Chrome 49 and Internet Explorer 9 the contence of the template is displayed directly in the head of the page and not further down the page as in Firefox (and as intended). Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

---

### Just to clarify. The link should be displayed in it's correct place in the table as in Firefox, but in Chrome and Explorer the link is shown immediately in top of the page and it's place in the table is blank.

Here is the full stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Document   : arende.xsl
  Created on : 6 april, 2016
  Author     : Paul Bergström
-->
<!--
  Declaration of usage of XLink Namespace
-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="xlink" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<!--
Attribute XLink defined as an href of simple type
-->
<xsl:template match="*[@xlink:type = 'simple' and @xlink:href]">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="//case/events/event/document">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//case/events/event/document/attachments/attachment">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Ärendekort</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Ärende</h2>
            <!--xsl:apply-templates select="case"/-->
        </body>
        </html>
<!--xsl:template match="case"-->
    <table border="1" max-width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Element namn</th>
        <th>Innehåll</th>
      </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//case/*[not(self::events)]">
    <tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/*[not(self::document)]">
     <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document">
        <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//case/events/event/document"/>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">          
        <xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document/debug_docSource">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document/attachments/attachment">
                    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//case/events/event/document/attachments/attachment"/>
                    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

    </table>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT, as I don't think the problem lies in the code you have shown us. You mention a table, so perhaps the HTML for that is not entirely correct (i.e perhaps you have a `td` tag that is not in a `tr` tag. Ideally we would like to see a complete XSLT that demonstrates the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this bit of code...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document">
    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
       <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//case/events/event/document"/>
    </tr>
```

This is going to output HTML like the following:

```
<tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
    <td>document</td>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
</tr>
```

So, you have an `a` tag that is not in a `td` tag but a direct child of `tr`. This is what is confusing the browsers. It really should be in a `td` tag too.

So, it probably should look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document">
    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
       <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
       <td><xsl:apply-templates select="//case/events/event/document"/></td>
    </tr>
```

In fact, you don't really need the full xpath expression in the `xsl:apply-templates` as you are already positioned on the `document` element. Try this too

```
<xsl:for-each select="//case/events/event/document">
    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
       <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
       <td><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works that way both in Chrome and Explorer. Funny though it worked correctlty in Firefox without the tag <td></td>?